# How do I read the RGB channels of an image in C?

Tags: c, cuda

I am using pycuda to compute the intensity of the pixels of an image. To this end, I have sent the image to the GPU as follows.

```
 img = np.float32(np.array(img.imread('my_image.jpg')))
 img_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(img)
```

Then, in a kernel (written in c of course), I want to get the RGB values as follows (in pseudocode).

```
__global__ void get_intensities(float* img, float* intensities) {
    intensities[globalIndex] = R(x, y) + G(x, y) + B(x, y)
}
```

My big problem now is getting the RGB channels in C. How do I do that?

Comment: First of all, you have to pass the width, height and stride of the image to the kernel. Second, it depends on how the pixels are stored in the image. e.g are the channels interleaved? like `R G B`, `B G R` etc.

Comment: I would also recommend thinking a bit more about your python code's variable names. The very first line of code has an egregious variable name conflict. You also haven't said which `imread` function you have used. This is really a python library question not a CUDA programming one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this ultimately depends on how the image is stored, I would take advantage of structs in this situation. For example:

```
image = np.uint8(np.array(img.imread('my_image.jpg')))
img_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(image)

__global__ void intensity(uchar3* img, int* intensities)
{
    ...
    intensities[globalIndex] = img[globalIndex].x + img[globalIndex].y + img[globalIndex].z;
    ...
}
```

See http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#built-in-vector-types

Comment: Thanks! Using that struct works! It looks like x is 'B', y is 'G', and z is 'R'.